# How to disable a menu option in the menu items i created in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menuitem

I created 6 menu items in the menu for the default launching screen and there is one option in the menu which is mandatory to launch before clicking on any other menu option. And it is not possible to display that particular as a default screen (due to the parameters in my project). So i want to disable all the other menu options so that the user is forced to click only that particular option. Is this possible? Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by disabled? Should it looked disabled, or just be disabled?  You can use a class variable to make sure nothing else runs until you say it can. In your makeMenu function, do something like this:

```
private boolean goAhead = false;
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance)
{
    menu.add(new MenuItem("Menu Item Mandatory Thing", 1, 1){
        public void run() 
        {
            //do stuff
            goAhead = true;
        }
    });;

    menu.add(new MenuItem("Menu Item 2", 2, 2){
        public void run() 
        {
            if(goAhead)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    });

    menu.add(new MenuItem("Menu Item 3", 3, 3){
        public void run() 
        {
            if(goAhead)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    });
}
```